# El carrusel de bootstrap no me va

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Copié el código de bootstrap del carrusel sin modificar nada, solo le puse unas imagenes para hacer unas pruebas y no rota. Los botones de Previo y Siguiente no funcionan. Este es el código de Bootstrap

```
<div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="..." alt="First slide">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="..." alt="Second slide">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="..." alt="Third slide">
    </div>
  </div>
  <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: A tu pregunta le faltan muchos detalles, están llamando correctamente las librerías?

Comment: Si, tengo rato trabajando con bootstrap y me va todo bien pero el carrusel no

Answer (score 1):

Es importante que te aseguros de tener las dependencias correctamente.

1. **el ccs de boostrap**

https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css

2. **la liberia jquery**

[https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"](https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js%22)

3. **el js de boostrap**

[https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"](https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js%22)

**También puedes validad en la consola si tu código tiene algún error de javascript.**

Answer (score 0):

Como veo es el ejemplo exacto tomado desde la página de bootstrap, quizás no agregaste la función inicialización.

```
<script>
    $('.carousel').carousel({
        interval: 2000
    })
</script>
```

esto suponiendo que agregó correctamente las dependencias

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>

        <!---css--->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-VCmXjywReHh4PwowAiWNagnWcLhlEJLA5buUprzK8rxFgeH0kww/aWY76TfkUoSX" crossorigin="anonymous">

    </head>
    <body>

        <!---Tu código html--->

        <!---js--->
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-XEerZL0cuoUbHE4nZReLT7nx9gQrQreJekYhJD9WNWhH8nEW+0c5qq7aIo2Wl30J" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Si, las tengo agregadas pero igual no me va :/ además como podría también cambiarle el tamaño? es que se ve muy grande y me ocupa toda la pantalla y quiero que sea más pequeño